# JavaMail - Issue with Multiple And Search Terms

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I would like to fetch recent, unread emails with a specific subject in a particular folder from my gmail account. I am using JavaMail API as below but it returns 0 results. However if I just use subjectTerm alone, I see results. Please let me know where am I going wrong. Thank you.

Please note that I used  messages[0] below instead of looping through messages array for code simplicity to paste it here.

```
     public void openMailBox(String hostname, String username, String password, String folderName, String subject) throws MessagingException, GeneralSecurityException, IOException{
        props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imap.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
        props.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory", new MailSSLSocketFactory()); 
        session = Session.getInstance(props);
        store = session.getStore();
        store.connect(username, password);
        folder = store.getFolder(folderName);
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        messages = folder.search(getSearchTerm(subject));
        if (messages[0].isMimeType("multipart/*")){
             Multipart multipart = (Multipart) messages[0].getContent();
             for(int i=0;i<multipart.getCount();i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(0);
                if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/*")) {
                    msg = msg+bodyPart.getContent().toString();
                }
             }
        }else{
            msg = messages[0].getContent().toString();
        }
        System.out.println(msg);
        folder.close(true);
        store.close();
    }

     public SearchTerm getSearchTerm(String subject){
         subjectTerm = new SubjectTerm(subject);
         unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
         recentFlagTerm; = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.RECENT), true);
         return new AndTerm(subjectTerm, new AndTerm(unseenFlagTerm, recentFlagTerm));    
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What mail server are you using?

Some mail servers don't implement the RECENT flag in any useful way, so messages might not be marked RECENT.  Try leaving out the RECENT term and see if you get more results.

If that doesn't help, add code to dump out the flags for all messages and then post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) that shows the flags for all messages along with the search request and response.

Note also that some IMAP servers don't fully or correctly implement the SEARCH command and so can't handle the kind of search you're doing.

Finally, note that you don't need to set the socketFactory property unless you're using MailSSLSocketFactory in a more interesting way than you've show in your example code above.

Comment: imap.gmail.com is the mail server. After I remove RECENT flag, it works fine. Thank you so much.